# CMD command to find a file and do something with this file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I want to use a batch file to find a file in my system and play with it.

I can use

```
dir filename /s /p
```

to find the location.

For example, if I ran the following

```
C:\Users\test>dir somejar.jar /s /p
 Volume in drive C is OS
 Volume Serial Number is 981C-D5F0

 Directory of C:\Users\test\.gradle\caches\artifacts-24\filestore\org.something\jar\1bd8c9fd8aee6dcac27f6d727a15eb7c65532e0

07/04/14  07:35 p.m.         2,530,874 somejar.jar
               1 File(s)      2,530,874 bytes

     Total Files Listed:
               1 File(s)      2,530,874 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  194,490,933,248 bytes free

C:\Users\test>
```

How do I make a batch file so once I open it, it will find this file and change its directory to where the file is located and play with this file?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
for /F "delims=" %s in ('dir /s /b filename') do cd "%s\.."
```

on the command line or replace `%s` by `%%s` to use in a batch file. How it works:

1. It uses `dir /s` as proposed by you, but without paging. Instead I use the simple output format (bare) `/b` to just get the file name.
2. Because we can't simply pipe (`|`) this into `cd`, we need the strange `for` command. Make sure that `for` does not start splitting at backslashes (`/F "delims="`).
3. Because we get the file name but want the directory instead, use `\..` to go up one level (from file to directory).